# Syntax for ASP.Net MVC Phil Haack's Repeater syntax using Razor (MVC 3)?

Tags: syntax, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have recently started using ASP.Net MVC 3 RC 2 and have attempted to migrate an existing website in MVC 2 across using the Razor syntax.  In the MVC 2 application I am using the code base repeater that Phil Haack kindly provided in the following:
[Phil Haack's Code Based Repeater](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/05/03/code-based-repeater-for-asp.net-mvc.aspx)

My question is around the syntax for Razor.  I dont understand how the template in the following block can be rewritten in Razor and cannot find any documentation to help out (early days for documentation or my simplicity...):

```
<% Html.Repeater<ObjectToUse>(Model, "", "alt", (item, css) =>
   { %>
        <tr class="<%= item.Enabled ? css : "disabled" %>">
            <td><%= item.Name%></td>
            <td><%= item.Description%></td>
            <td><%= Html.RouteLink("Edit", item.ObjectToUseRouteValues("Edit"))%></td>
            <td></td>
            <td><%= Html.RouteLink("Select", item.ObjectToUseRouteValues())%></td>
        </tr>
<% }); %>
```

The problem comes when applying the template between the braces (the tr's).  I have attempted using the WebGrid control, however it doesnt provide the functionality I require for setting a "disabled" row (I think).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, now that I think about it some more I don't think you can use `Action` parameters like that in Razor. I recall running into this before.

### Updated

With answer from Andrew Nurse:
"*Unfortunately this is by design in the current parser, though I should note that we'd like to improve upon it.  The issue is that markup is only valid at the start of a statement (which technically is where you've put it), but our C# "parser" is not intelligent enough to detect lambdas at the moment.*"

Though that might be out dated :)

```
@Html.Repeater(Model, "row", "row-alt", 
    @<tr class="@item.ClassType : "disabled"">
        <td>@item.Name</td>
        <td>@item.Description</td>
        <td>@Html.RouteLink("Edit", item.ObjectToUseRouteValues("Edit"))</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>@Html.RouteLink("Select", item.ObjectToUseRouteValues())</td>
    </tr>
)

    public static IHtmlString Repeater<T>(this HtmlHelper html, IEnumerable<T> items,
         string className, string classNameAlt, Func<T, HelperResult> render) {
        if (items == null)
            return new HtmlString("");

        int i = 0;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (var item in items) {
            item.ClassType = item.Enabled ? (i++ % 2 == 0 ? className : classNameAlt) : "disabled";
            sb.Append(render(item).ToHtmlString());
        }

        return new HtmlString(sb.ToString());
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi, I had tried this, however the problem is in how the compiler perceives the html in the delegate function.  It doesnt seem to recognise it as it does in the c# aspx implementation.  So between the { <tr></tr> } it sees them as random  pieces of text rather than as a string.

Comment: Updated I don't think it's possible

Comment: Probably best to ask Haacked...I'm afraid my answer just sucks

Comment: This is correct, unfortunately we don't have a smart enough parser to detect lambdas right now.  It _would_ be possible to rewrite the helper to use the Inline Template syntax, in fact, I did exactly that here: http://blog.andrewnurse.net/2010/08/02/InsideRazorPart3Templates.aspx

Comment: Thanks, I was pretty sure that was the case but I not entirely confident :)

Answer (score 1):

I wrote `@helper` version.
`@helper` do not use Generic method.

```
@helper ForEach(IEnumerable<int> items, Func<object, HelperResult> template){
    foreach(var item in items){
        Write(template(item));
    }
}
<div>
<ul>
@ForEach(Enumerable.Range(1,5),
    @<li>@item</li>
)
</ul>
</div>
```

hope this code.