# How do I use UrlHelper from within a Razor helper?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, helper

I'm trying to create a Razor helper like this:

```
@helper Render(IEnumerable<MyItem> items) {
  <ul>
    @foreach (var item in items) {
      <li><a href="@Url.Content(item.Url)">Click</a></li>
    }
  </ul>
}
```

Only problem here is that System.Web.WebPages.HelperPage (the base class for Razor helpers) doesn't have a Url property (of type UrlHelper). It DOES have Html (of type HtmlHelper) but no Url.

What's the cleanest way to get at a UrlHelper inside a helper? Should I new one up inline?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

[Syntax for ASP.Net MVC Phil Haack's Repeater syntax using Razor (MVC 3)? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4444022/syntax-for-asp-net-mvc-phil-haacks-repeater-syntax-using-razor-mvc-3/4482731#4482731)

```
@helper Render(IEnumerable<MyItem> items) {
  var url = new System.Web.Mvc.UrlHelper(Context.Request.RequestContext);
  <ul>
    @foreach (var item in items) {
      <li><a href="@url.Content(item.Url)">Click</a></li>
    }
  </ul>
}
```

or, If using MVC3 RC2

```
@helper Render(IEnumerable<MyItem> items) {
  <ul>
    @foreach (var item in items) {
      <li><a href="@Href(item.Url)">Click</a></li>
    }
  </ul>
}
```

Hope this help.

Comment: The answer you linked to doesn't use UrlHelper...?

Answer (score 7):

I was trying to do the same thing and found this post.

I solved my problem by using `@VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~/foo/bar.jpg")` instead of `@Url.Content("~/foo/bar.jpg")`

Since `@VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute()` is static, it's available everywhere.  Plus I didn't have to add any references or anything, it worked out-of-the-box from my Razor view.

If you need to use `@Url.Action` or `@Url.RouteUrl`, you'll probably want to find a real `UrlHelper` ... but for `@Url.Content` (which is what I was trying to use too), `@VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute()` works great!

Answer (score 0):

```
    @helper Render(IEnumerable<MyItem> items,UrlHelper url) {
  <ul>
    @foreach (var item in items) {
      <li><a href="@url.Content(item.Url)">Click</a></li>
    }
  </ul>
}
```