# Complete @Url Helper in @helper declaration

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

**Is there a way to get access to the full `@Url` helper object inside an `@helper` declaration?**

I want to do something like this...

```
@helper Button(System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult action, string text)
{
    <input type="button" name="btn" value="@text" onclick="windows.location='@Url.Action(action)'" />
}
```

*I found [**this question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4522807/how-do-i-use-urlhelper-from-within-a-razor-helper) but this solution does not get you access to `@Url.Action(ActionResult)`.  Please note the specific overload that I am looking for.*

So has anyone figured out a solution to this one?  I could always do the extension method style for custom helpers, but I like the @helper style and I've already run into this problem a few times.

Thanks in advance, everybody!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a way to get access to the full @Url helper object inside an @helper declaration?

Yes, by passing it as argument to the helper method.

```
@helper Button(string action, string text, UrlHelper url)
{
    <input type="button" name="btn" value="@text" onclick="windows.location='@url.Action(action)'" />
}
```

and when you invoke the helper from some view:

```
@Button("someAction", "some text", Url)
```

Comment: Great idea, but it does not work, or I am doing something wrong.  I tried the following and the only overloads of the action method that I get are the ones that take the action name as a string...

    `@helper ActionButton(System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult action, string text, System.Web.Mvc.UrlHelper url)
    {
        <input type="button" name="@action.ToString()" value="@text" onclick="window.locaiton='@url.Action(action)'" />
    }`

Comment: @jrizzo, what overloads of the Action method that do not take a string that you are talking about? There is no overload that of the UrlHelper.Action method that takes a `System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult` as a first argument that I am aware of. You must be trying something wrong.

Comment: I'm looking for the overload that takes an `ActionResult`.

Comment: @jrizzo, ???????????? I am afraid that the overload you are looking for simply doesn't exist. Take a look at the documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.urlhelper.action.aspx

Comment: Hmmm... I can't find the documentation, but if I type `@Url.Action(myActionResult)` in a regular .cshtml page, the _first_ overload in Intellisense takes an `ActionResult`.  Maybe It's part of an package I have...  I'll get back to you if I figure out which one it is (or let me know if anyone else knows...).

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about the Razor, but for html helpers Yes you can. using RequestContext of the helper as shown below. here is one example I wrote for ImageFor html helper:

```
    public static HtmlString ImageFor(this HtmlHelper helper, string url ) 
    {
        var urlHelper = new UrlHelper(helper.ViewContext.RequestContext);
        TagBuilder tb = new TagBuilder("img");
        tb.MergeAttribute("src", urlHelper.Content(url));
        return new HtmlString(tb.ToString(TagRenderMode.SelfClosing)); 
    }
```