# Shifting @helper code to App_Code folder throwing error

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have a `@heper pagination` function. That is having two View helper `ViewBag` and `Url`.
This pagination is going to be used by so many pages so i shift the code from `Views` folder 
to `App_Code` folder. Code inside `App_Code/Helper.cshtml`

```
@helper buildLinks(int start, int end, string innerContent)
{
     for (int i = start; i <= end; i++)
     {   
         <a class="@(i == ViewBag.CurrentPage ? "current" : "")" href="@Url.Action("index", "country", new { page = i })">@(innerContent ?? i.ToString())</a>
     }   
}
```

But now when I run the app. it throws error

```
error CS0103:The name 'ViewBag' does not exist in the current context
error CS0103:The name 'Url' does not exist in the current context
```

Do I need to import any namespace or where the problem is?

The way I want to do is perfect?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Mark said, you should pass the UrlHelper as parameter to your helper:

```
@helper buildLinks(int start, int end, int currentPage, string innerContent, System.Web.Mvc.UrlHelper url)
{
     for (int i = start; i <= end; i++)
     {   
         <a class="@(i == currentPage ? "current" : "")" href="@url.Action("index", "country", new { page = i })">@(innerContent ?? i.ToString())</a>
     }   
}
```

and then call it like this fomr a view:

```
@Helper.buildLinks(1, 10, ViewBag.CurrentPage, "some text", Url)
```

Comment: Darin, why would I want to pass in the Url if I can pick it up from the RequestContext as I posted in my comment to @akakey's reply?

Comment: I don't want to pass currentPage as a parameter. @akakey has found the better one.

Comment: See @akakey answer below, it should be marked as the correct answer

Answer (score 13):

Well actually you can access ViewBag from helpers inside App_Code folder like this:

```
@helper buildLinks()
{
    var p = (System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage)PageContext.Page;

    var vb = p.ViewBag;

    /* vb is your ViewBag */
}
```

Comment: this answer is the cleanest.  I don't know why it wasn't selected as such.  For completeness, the @Url can be accessed as shown here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4522807/how-do-i-use-urlhelper-from-within-a-razor-helper

Answer (score 4):

If you moved your helpers to App_Code then you have to pass the `ViewBag`, `UrlHelper`, `HtmlHelper` to the functions from your views.

Ex.

**html helper function in App_code**

```
@helper SomeFunc(System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper Html)
{
    ...
}
```

**From your view,**

```
@SomeFunc("..", Html) // passing the html helper
```

Comment: Yes you can use that but the helpers you have to pass from view

Comment: Can you post what you are trying to achieve