# Is there a free DataList or Repeater type helper for MVC3/4?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm looking for something like the WebForms DataList or Repeater controls for my MVC4 eStore application, to show product partial views repeated across and down, with paging. Paging is actually just a nice to have, so I could fall back on a plain horizontal ul structure, but I was hoping there may me a quick and free improvement.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, look at `EditorTemplate` and `DisplayTemplate`. You create partial view and then `@Html.EditorFor` will make all job. [ASP.NET MVC 3 – How to use EditorTemplates](http://coding-in.net/asp-net-mvc-3-how-to-use-editortemplates/)

Comment: Thank you, but I would still have to write quite a lot of code for the editor template for the structure and control I am looking for. I asked the question in the hope of avoiding that.

Comment: @ProfK You are looking for this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4444022/syntax-for-asp-net-mvc-phil-haacks-repeater-syntax-using-razor-mvc-3 ?

Comment: No, I am looking for more than a plain loop. I am looking for a grid but that repeats horizontally as well, with bells and whistles.

Comment: @ProfK In this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/177275/grid-controls-for-asp-net-mvc you can find **MVCContrib Grid**

Comment: I need it to repeat across and down. None of the grids I have looked at do that.